# Getting image from Sharepoint post with Microsoft Graph

Tags: image, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

My company has made a custom photo-field in Sharepoint for it's news. I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to fetch the images, but with no success.

This is the columns description:

```
{ 
        "columnGroup": "Page Layout Columns",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "Thumbnail image",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "PublishingPageImage",
        "readOnly": false,
        "required": false
    },
```

In the documentation for `Microsoft Graph` it is written that you can make a request like this

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=Column1,Column2)
```

Although - no matter how I seem to write the request, i can't get the image field.

My most recent try has been this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/knowit.sharepoint.com/lists/posts/items?expand=fields(select=PublishingPageImage)
```

The respons I got from Microsoft was this:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientServiceException",
    "message": "Cannot serialize data for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.ImageFieldValue.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "f25e4851-0c1b-4061-ad6a-948d38004046",
        "date": "2018-09-17T14:03:01"
    }
}
```

}

Should I use something like `.value`  or `.data` or `.ImageUrl` after the request? If i get a link or a data-value doesn't really matter. In the call for `/me/` for Microsoft users there is a `$value` property for getting the user profile photo. Is it something like this?

Comment: Based on the test on C#, it should be have a property ImageUrl, but i have not confirmed if it works well on Graph

Answer (score 1):

It depends how image is stored.
If it is attachment you can do following:

```
  string baseURL = $"https://{spTenant}/_api/web/lists('{ AA.config.listID}')/items({ siteData.Id})/AttachmentFiles";
        string fileName = await GetFileNameAsync(baseURL);
        string getPictureReqUrl = $"{baseURL}('{fileName}')/$value";
        Stream responseStream = await GetPictureAsync(getPictureReqUrl);

     private static async Task<Stream> GetPictureAsync(string reqUrl)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", SPOToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(reqUrl);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
```

**Important! This is not supported by graph yet, but you can use SharePoint Rest API**

If picture is stored in document library you need to use Drive object instead
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/drive